# Position textview on top of clicked imageview

Tags: android, layout, textview, imageview, addition

Is there a way to programatically add `TextView` and show it right next to the `ImageView` user clicked on?

I tried something like this, but no results, `TextView` is added to the bottom of my layout:

```
TextView score = new TextView(getBaseContext());
score.setText("Image clicked");
Rect rectf = new Rect();
im.getLocalVisibleRect(rectf);
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 300, 270);
score.setLayoutParams(params);
layout.addView(score);
```

Comment: what is parant layout of image, is it RelativeLayout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, never use **AbsoluteLayout**, never! AbsoluteLayout is generally not recommended and you shouldn't use it. I recommend to you use `RelativeLayout` and then you only need to add rule.

Try to use following snippet of code:

```
relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
par = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
par.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, imageView.getId());
relativeLayout.addView(score, par);
```

Comment: No, the parent layout of image is LinearLayout.  I'm gonna try this code now and let you now if it works. Thanks!

Comment: so you are doing something bad.

Comment: I added the same code as you posted, except that I used:
    relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(MyClass.this);
because I'm doing this inside of onClick() method. I tried looking at view hierarchy but I can't see this relativeLayout anywhere...Any ideas?

Comment: try to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394293/create-a-new-textview-programmatically-then-display-it-below-another-textview).

Comment: Can't figure it out. When I put RelativeLayout in my main XML layout, textView is shown, but of course on the wrong place. When I create RelativeLayout with a constructor, I get nothing. It's like in this way, RelativeLayout is never attached my parent layout.