# android Log history just download and upload

Tags: android

I want get just download and upload history from browser in android and save it in database,can or not?help me plz, and display it in  linearlayout(vertical) Can teach me step by step?

Answer (score 0):

You should start reading :
[Browser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html)
[SO similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577084/android-read-browser-history)

I would recommend a listview, but if you want to use LinearLayout, you can create TextViews dinamically while you iterate the `Cursor` returned:

```
TextView tv=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tv.setText("text blah blah");
layout.addView(tv);
```

Look at this question: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394293/create-a-new-textview-programmatically-then-display-it-below-another-textview)

Comment: do I need to create new java or just put in the existing java?