# What would be a better approach to display a same layout more than one time?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-cardview

Suppose I have a `CardView` which contains 2 `TextView`, and I need to display 10 `CardView` with same layout as 10 times one below the other

**These 10 will always be fixed, it will never be more or less than 10 in the future.**

What would be a better approach among the 2 given below (in terms of performance)?

**1st Approach** :

Type the code for all the 10 `CardView` in xml 10 times and set their individual `TextView`'s value in Java Code

**2nd approach** :

Type the code for only one `CardView` and use it in a "`ListView`" or "`RecyclerView`" to display it 10 times in Java code

Or can you suggest any other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the second approach is better.

You just need to use View holder to optimize user experience.

The **ViewHolder** pattern is a pattern that a developer can use to increase the speed at which their ListView renders data. 
The reason for this improvement is that the number of times which the findViewById method is invoked is drastically reduced, 
existing views do not have to be garbage collected and new views do not have to be inflated.

Check these links to understand more about view holder and its usefulness

[Android Developer Documentation -Making ListView Scrolling Smooth](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

[Optimizing Your Listview](https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview)

[Android ViewHolder Pattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

[Android RecyclerView](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html)

Comment: @Christiana214 Thank You for giving explanation and sharing the links.
That was really helpful in increasing the performance

Comment: Your Welcome Avtar, oh I also read in the comment below that you're having problem in displaying different number of textview in each listItem.

Comment: You can achieved it dynamically by creating a gridview inside the listview, while the gridview will inflate the textview , you will also use view holder in this. I created an illustration http://imgur.com/kHQp4Uf .

Comment: This is what I have to do, http://imgur.com/AT89C7q      , the outer black is "recyclerView",...the red one is "cardView",..the Blue one is another "cardView" (containing 2 textviews always, it will always remain 2 texitviews),...now the outer "Black-recyclerView" may contain near about 15 or 20 "Red-cardView"......But the main problem I am having is the following one...the "Red-cardView" can sometime contain "1 blue-cardView" or "2 blue-cardView" or "3 blue-cardView"...Now tell me how to do this...Please tell in detail explanation as I am not used to RecyclerView and its Adapter

Comment: as what I understand cardview is like a layout container that you can put views like textview. so in order to achieved what you want .the number of textviews in a cardview is fixed 2 , but number of cardview is nth. you just need listview -that inflates Gridview, Gridview will inflate Cardview inside it is 2 textview. Baseadapter inside baseadapter.

Comment: I will send you sample code next monday. Same as my image illustion  but the textview in there will be cardview.

Comment: Yes almost same as your image, I tried but was not able to have that nested thing, try it, If you get anything working then tell me, Anyways, Thank You for all

Comment: I made it worked before, gonna show the code next time. as of now I gotta  go .

Comment: this is the sample  check it out https://github.com/cristiana214/NestedAdapterView

Comment: @AvtarSingh what happen next?

Comment: I was Off for 2 days, Now Testing your Sample Code, Just give me some time

Comment: Hey @Cristiana214 This is Exactly what I was trying to do, Perfect, Thank You Very Very Much (Y)

Comment: Great! :-D i'm glad it helps.

Comment: Hey @Cristiana214 Can you help me in creating the layout similar to this Video, the coordinator layout and then the transparent toolbar on collapsing it...its just not happening...I don't know exactly how to do it...please help...https://dl.pushbulletusercontent.com/rezXzeTxwRdGxvi9fLJUOw4VKccxjNue/2015_09_14_23_37_58.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Second approach more flexible. In terms performance and especially in terms of code management in future.

Comment: Yeah I too thought that 2nd Approach will be more Flexible in terms of code management. But I think that it would be slightly slow. May be, I am not sure. Just a bit Confused. What you Say ?

Comment: If it was 10 rows only means it will not affect that much in performance. And also you have two `textview`s only per rows. So don't worry about performance here.

Comment: Yes.. 2nd approach is optimal in terms of `layout rendering` and `memory`.. It is also open for expansion if in case requirement changes in future..

Comment: @Kushal Yeah you are right that "It is also open for expansion if in case requirement changes in future"    ,     But, why are you saying that it is optimal in terms of "layout rendering" and "memory"  ,   I was thinking that there will be alight delay on loading that activity because "ListView" will be creating 10 layouts. Can you clarify my doubt in detail why it would be more optimal to use 2nd Approach PLEASE

Comment: `RecyclerView` and `ListView` re-uses views when user scrolls across.. Further, `RecyclerView` is optimal `ListView` provided by Android.. so it is optimal in terms of layout rendering because of re-use using `getView()` callback.. even more optimal if we use `ViewHolder` inside `getView()`..

Comment: @Kushal Thank You. Just one more thing. I got another problem just now. Suppose a CardView will contain 2 textviews, and 2nd cardview may contain 1 textview or more and next cardview may contain 4 textviews, so how to tackle that, but notice that number of total cardview will always be 10. Please help in how to tackle this thing.....should I manually write all cardview with different layout in xml or you have some other trick, but performance should not be degraded

Comment: Have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394293/create-a-new-textview-programmatically-then-display-it-below-another-textview) and [here](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=create%20textview%20programmatically%20android) @AvtarSingh

Comment: @Gunaseelan I did that, and it is working fine, but i dont wanna use this approach as I think that Creating textviews at runtime is not really preferred. It will be slow , I think

Comment: @AvtarSingh How did you say it will be slow... If you add it by xml work we have to inflate xml, then have find our textview as integer, then have to convert it as textview, then only we can set text or do operations on that textview.

Comment: If you only see 2 or 3 CardViews on screen at a time, RecyclerView will be faster to render.