# How to save textview in layout by SharedPreferences

Tags: android

i built some text view programmatically and i want to save them in my layout but i do not know how to do it.is Shared Preferences do that ? and how ?

here is my code

```
LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
String[] textArray = { weatherResult };
for (int i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
TextView textView = new TextView(RestFulWebservice.this);
textView.setText(textArray[i]);
main.addView(textView);
```

i checked this question but it was not what i want.
[Create a new TextView programmatically then display it below another TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394293/create-a-new-textview-programmatically-then-display-it-below-another-textview)

Comment: can you please explain more what your are trying to do?

Comment: you can't save textview. You can only save it's text alongwith position from array

Comment: @VivekMishra   you mean there is no chance to save their state in layout?

Comment: @saeed , what do you mean "their state"? text inside or what?  Write here your case for saving. I'm do not understand your "saving" mode:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't save textview, I think you need code like this to save texts for your textview

```
String[] textArray = { "" };
    for (int i = 0; i < textArray.length; ++i) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("textview_" + i + "_text", textArray[i]);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: and how one will map them again without position?

Comment: and how can i Retrieve  it

Comment: you can get it back by this code

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
for (int  i = 0; i < textArray.length; ++i) {
        String currentText = sharedPreferences.getString("textview_" + i + "_text", "");
   /* ------ your code ------*/
}