# How to programmatically create textviews and show as grid

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

[Create a new TextView programmatically then display it below another TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394293/create-a-new-textview-programmatically-then-display-it-below-another-textview)

This is what I have tried,but it didn't help.

I need to programmatically create few textview and then display them like this as a grid

In first line : 1st Textview  2nd Textview
second line   : 3rd Textview    4th Textview

I'm setting the texts from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon the linked question this is what will work for you

```
    String[] textArray = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four","Five","Six"};
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for( int i = 0; i < textArray.length; i+=2 )
    {
        LinearLayout linearLayout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
        textView1.setText(textArray[i]);
        TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
        textView2.setText(textArray[i+1]);
        linearLayout1.addView(textView1);
        linearLayout1.addView(textView2);
        linearLayout.addView(linearLayout1);
    }
    <mainLayout>.addView(linearLayout);
```

Further more you can add `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` to set the content however you like. And if you'd like to center it then you can use weights