# Relative Layout adding views programmatically one below other not aligning correctly

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, android-layoutparams

I am trying to add Text views programmatically to Relative layout parent one below other. However, the first view is not aligning correctly while the rest of the view got aligned correctly. See attached image.

[image]

My code:

```
private void setupQuestionChoices(int position) {
    question.setText(questionList.get(position).question());
    choicesTextViewsList.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < questionList.get(position).choices().size(); i++) {

        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());

        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.qa_button_background);
        textView.setMinWidth(300);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        textView.setText(questionList.get(position).choices().get(i));
        textView.setId(i);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        if (i == 0) {
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, question.getId());
        } else {
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, choicesTextViewsList.get(i - 1).getId());
        }
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        layoutParams.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
        relativeLayout.addView(textView, layoutParams);

        choicesTextViewsList.add(textView);

        choicesTextViewsList.get(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                answerSelected = true;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Relative layout xml where I add my views to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_parent" //here is where I add views to
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_back"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_border"
                android:text="Back"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_next"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_border"
                android:text="Next"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I read some posts related to this issue and followed the guidelines from them but that did not help.

[How to lay out Views in RelativeLayout programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/how-to-lay-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically)

[Create a new TextView programmatically then display it below another TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394293/create-a-new-textview-programmatically-then-display-it-below-another-textview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the index of the `for` loop as id for the textViews which I changed to make Android generate Id for it as below and it is working fine now as expected.

I changed the line

`textView.setId(i)`

to

`textView.setId(ViewGroup.generateViewId())`

Thanks.