# How to add a new Textview evertime Button is clicked

Tags: java, android, button, textview

I created a LinearLayout with a Button and I want to add a new Textview everytime the button is clicked. This is the code I wrote but it does not work for me:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            linearLayout).addView(textView);


            }
        });
```

and this is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="+" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make a recyclerview and with every click add one item to it

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204852/how-to-add-a-textview-to-linearlayout-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your button onClickListener You need to create new textview and then add it to Your LinearLayout. Look at this StackOverflow: [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717206/9309845). Linked thread shows similar problem.
Be aware that if You want to have a lot of those TextViews, then You should consider using RecyclerView.

Comment: Please describe what You did and what is not working. Did You added ID to LinearLayout and then added TextView to it?  
'linearLayout.addView(textView);' This snippet adds TextView named textview (constructed like this: TextView textView = new TextView(this);) to LinearLayout named 'linearLayout'.  You need to find Your LinearLayout by its id attribute using findViewById()

Comment: Thank you the link in the response was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this :

```
((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(textView);
```

Where linearLayout is the id of your LinearLayout and textView the id of your TextView.